# Thumbs.db image extraction Java

Tags: java, thumbnails, javax.imageio

I am looking for a way to extract the images from thumbs.db file in java. I have tried using the method provided by another  [user here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129450/how-to-extract-images-from-thumbs-db-in-java). The segment of his code i am having trouble with is

```
    JPEGImageDecoder decoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGDecoder(is);
    JPEGDecodeParam param = JPEGCodec.getDefaultJPEGEncodeParam(4,JPEGDecodeParam.COLOR_ID_RGBA);
    decoder.setJPEGDecodeParam(param);
    BufferedImage originalBufferedImage = decoder.decodeAsBufferedImage();
```

I am getting the error JPEGImageDecoder cannot be resolved as a type.

Comment: Did you try pressing _control+shift+o_ ?

Comment: Tried that didn't fix the problem, thanks for the help though. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Is JPEGImageDecoder from any library?

Comment: After looking into this further apparently this has been deprecated in JDK7 http://blog.idrsolutions.com/2012/05/replacing-the-deprecated-java-jpeg-classes-for-java-7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not using POI as in the other example, but you can use my free, open source [Thumbs.db plugin for ImageIO](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys#ms-windows-thumbs-db-thumbsdb) to read the thumbnails.

When dependencies are set up, you can use it something like this:

```
ImageInputStream input = ImageIO.createImageInput(new File("/path/thumbs.db"));
ImageReader reader = ImageIO.getImageReaders(input).next();
reader.setInput(input);

for (int i = 0; i < reader.getNumImages(); i++) {
    BufferedImage thumb = reader.getImage(i, null);

    // do something with it...
}

reader.dispose(); // These last two, preferably in a finally block or "try-with-resource"
input.close();
```

If you want to see more in detail how the images are decoded, you can have a look at the source for [ThumbsDBImageReader.java](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/blob/master/imageio/imageio-thumbsdb/src/main/java/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/plugins/thumbsdb/ThumbsDBImageReader.java).

---

PS: If you rather like to use POI, I think that you can replace your code above with something like this (for each Entry in `root`):

```
BufferedImage originalBufferedImage = ImageIO.read(is);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you help and providing your plugin for me to use.

Comment: One more question if you dont mind, where you said "think that you can replace your code above with something like this (for each Entry in root):  BufferedImage thumb = ImageIO.read(is); What do you mean

Comment: @ZakHilton You can replace the 4 lines in your question, with that line, and the [code from the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6129729/1428606) you referred should work.

Comment: Are i see i have got it working now thank you, i apologise if the  things i have been asking are a bit stupid and obvious  im just very new to this part of java ahah.

Comment: Just curious does your plugin support the later thumbnail format used by windows vista onward, the thumbnailcache format

Comment: @ZakHilton Probably not... I haven't made any changes to it since the last version of Windows I used, which was XP... ;-) If you find that it doesn't work, please [file an issue](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/issues) and send me a sample file or two + perhaps links to a spec of format description, I'll have a look at it.

Comment: @ZakHilton Update. I can't find anything about the format being different, only the location of the `.db` files. If so, it should work with no problem.

Comment: i hope so it will be very useful for what im doing, i will be trying it out tomorrow thank you once again

Comment: just tried it now getting the error           java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.next(Unknown Source)
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO$ImageReaderIterator.next(Unknown Source)
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO$ImageReaderIterator.next(Unknown Source)
 at interview.test.main(test.java:25)                               Im guessing they changed the the format in which the thumbnails are stored

Comment: If you have trouble, please file an issue and attach a thumbs.db file that can't be read. However, from the stack trace above, it looks more like you are missing some dependencies. You don't find a reader, and this happens before a read is even attempted.